# What do the icons mean in the monodevelop solution?

Tags: monodevelop

Why do some files have a pencil icon, some have a plus, some have none? What to do they mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. It's the git status of the files.

Modified, Added, etc..